# C# Webbrowser: Specifying Max-Device-Width

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, media-queries, webbrowser-control

I am working on a Web application that uses the Windows Forms C# Webbrowser to take screenshots of Web pages and save them for archiving purposes.

I am running into an issue with pages that use max-device-width in CSS media queries for responsive layout.

Apparently the max-device-width for the Webbrowser control defaults to 1024 px which causes certain CSS rules to fire resulting in layout issues.

Using max-width in the media queries would probably fix this, but would have the undesired effects when resizing the browser window on desktop browsers.

Is there some way of specifying the max-device-width of the Webbrowser?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what is the width of your monitor?

Comment: I am seeing this behavior both on my workstation (monitor is definitely larger than 1024 px wide) and on a server (Virtual Machine) which does not have a monitor attached.